# say with \n\r newline with Perl

Tags: perl, dos

I would like to use `say` with a dos newline format:

`say "foo"` should display `foo\r\n`

I tried to redefine the new line variable but it doesn't change anything

```
 local $/="\r\n";
```

Another solution would be to manually write:

```
 print "foo\r\n";
```

But it is not very convenient

Comment: `local $\ ="\r\n"; print "foo";`

Comment: Oh ! I didn't know that both `$/` and `$\\` exists

Comment: DOS newline is `\r\n`

Comment: @M42 you're right :)

Comment: @coin for all your special variable needs, may I recommend perlvar: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use global vars that affect all handles; use

```
open(my $fh, '>:crlf', ...)
```

or

```
binmode($fh, ':crlf')
```

`:crlf` is already added for you by default on Windows machines, but specifying it in `open` or trying to add it to a handle that already has it using `binmode` won't hurt.

Comment: That's the best way to do it.